# twitter bootstrap - setting column height based on max column height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make all the columns to same height in a row. So, all columns in a row should have the same height as any column with max height.

**Fiddler:** https://jsfiddle.net/ebwwvy6m/11/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 bg-warning">
      This is a col-sm-2
      Some test content
       Some test content
        Some test content
         Some test content
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 bg-success">
      .col-sm-6
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 bg-info">
      .col-sm-4      
      Some test content
      Some test content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Issue:**

[image]

Both column 2 and column 3 should expand to have the same height as column 1.

Any help / suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.row-eq-height{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}
```

Add this class with your row class.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-eq-height row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 bg-warning">
      This is a col-sm-2
      Some test content
       Some test content
        Some test content
         Some test content
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 bg-success">
      .col-sm-6
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 bg-info">
      .col-sm-4      
      Some test content
      Some test content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ebwwvy6m/16/

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is using **`display:flex;`** on the parent `row` and on the `col`.

**Working [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ebwwvy6m/13/).**

```css
.example {
  display: flex;
}
.example .exaple-items {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row example">
    <div class="col-sm-2 bg-warning exaple-items">
      This is a col-sm-2
      Some test content
       Some test content
        Some test content
         Some test content
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 bg-success exaple-items">
      .col-sm-6
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 bg-info exaple-items">
      .col-sm-4      
      Some test content
      Some test content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Since `flextbox` is a new CSS feature **check the browser compatibility**: [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

And use the **`vendor prefix`**:

```
.example {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}
```

If you want to know more about `display:flex;` read this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

**P.S.** The [new bootstrap v4](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/flexbox/) will have this feature integrated.

Comment: @paola, display:flex seems to work in IE 11 and above. What about the other widely used versions of IE (like IE 9, IE10 etc?). Correct me if I missing anything.

Comment: Check the compatibility there: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox
It's a partial support in IE11 and IE10 (won't work in IE9-)

Comment: I've just check and in IE11 works pretty well: http://i.imgur.com/fZljpiI.png

Answer (score 0):

Add your own class and set height.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 (for the layzy)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 bg-warning my-super-class">
      This is a col-sm-2
       Some test content
        Some test content
         Some test content
          Some test content
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 bg-success my-super-class">
      .col-sm-6
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 bg-info my-super-class">
      .col-sm-4      
      Some test content
      Some test content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


.my-super-class {
  min-height: 12em;
}
```

Option 2: give the col's id, grab said DOMelement by their Id's in JavaScript. Then check for the biggest of them all, and use that value to set the (min-)height for all.